# PHP for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, php

I want to use PHP on my Mac.

If I were using Windows I would install WAMP server, but I'm not familiar with how to use PHP on Mac OS X. What kind of software should I use for installing/running my php developed sites locally on my Mac?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) is the equivalent of WAMP for Mac OS X.

Comment: I would give you +5, if i could.

Comment: MAMP would be my first choice. Excellent program.

Comment: I think that MAMP is no longer a normal AMP stack (seems like it disallows virtual hosts in the free version?). Are there any alternatives? I found an "install mysql and you're done" here: http://echodittolabs.org/blog/2011/08/os-x-107-lion-development-native-mamp-mysql-installer

Comment: @Yar: Well, I suppose that's what you get for convenience. I'm not aware of any other application that does this, so your best bet would be to manually install and configure each part, like in the article you linked.

Comment: Horrific. I might just run this stuff on Linux instead. At least that way I'm playing with one of the possible deployment platforms.

Answer (score 6):

PHP comes pre-installed in Mac OS X. It's not perfect for everyone (as it may or may not have the extensions you wish). To enable it (PHP 5.3 on Snow Leopard) you need to enable it in Apache 2's configuration file (Uncomment the php5.so module).

Applications such as [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) provide a separate installation of the *AMP stack that work on Mac OS X.

Alternatively if you want to install other versions of PHP on your Mac you can either use [MacPorts](http://macports.org) or compile it yourself.

From the way you are wording your question it sounds like you are not looking for how to use PHP on Mac OS X but how to set up the web development stack (Apache, MySQL, PHP) on your Mac.

Comment: Hey ! A great thing. On which version of Snow Leopard? A great Answer. You are aware of most of the things.

Comment: Both Server and Client come with PHP 5.3. All versions of Mac OS X came with versions as well (Leopard had PHP 5.2, Tiger 4.3, even older versions not worth mentioning)

Answer (score 2):

Marc Liyanage very kindly maintains a current build of PHP for Mac OS X at his [website](http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/): http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/

Go there, download it, follow the installation instructions, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [mac ports](http://www.macports.org/). Although it is difficult to setup initially, but once setup, its very easy to add packages. You can install new servers/memcached/mysql/php just by few commands.

There are many articles on google on installing Macports and then installing AMP. I found [this](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP) article helpful.

Comment: Hi Saurabh, welcome to SuperUser. Your answer is pretty close to the one posted by Chealion from October 2009. I would suggest editing it to improve the quality and information on it. Take a look at the [FAQ] for some tips.