# Free Database Utilities / Tools for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, database, query

If I were using Windows and wanted to use a database I would set up a WAMP server.

What can I use for Mac OS X?

I'm currently using SQLite via Mike's T Sqlite / Firefox addon for SQLite.

I would like to know what databases are available? (eg. MySQL for PHP, SQLite for PHP/iPhone). Are there any other database systems available that I can install? (For free?)

Comment: You might want to ask your question on StackOverflow.  There are many database developers there.  Although, your question seems a bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle's free database query tool is [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html).  It's written primarily in Java, so it runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

[MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) is one of them.

I got the details from this question: [PHP for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/56755/php-for-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

Both the primary open source SQL (relational) DBMS - MySQL and PostgreSQL - are readily available for Mac.  So is Firebird.

Choose your DBMS - the chances are decent that it is available for Mac unless you insist on something from Microsoft.  Go to its home site; look for it.